# How to setup a jenkins "Master" job which executes the subjobs sequentially without modifying the subjobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Is it possible to setup a job X to build a sequence of jobs A, B and C sequentially (B does not start before A finished successfully C does not start before B....) without specifying in B that is should start after A is done etc?
Precisely I would like to setup a "Master" job which executes the subjobs sequentially without modifying the subjobs.
(OR)
Is there a way to specify which all jobs to run sequentially from a list file or text file??

Can I use some plugin to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try the plugin [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)